Isomorphisms from the external sum of modules to the internal sum
Is this true: Let $R$ be a ring with a $1$. Let $(N_{i})_{i \in I}$ be a collection of $R$-submodules of the $R$-module $M$. If
$$\sum_{i \in I}N_{i} \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}N_{i}$$
then the map $f: \bigoplus_{i \in I}N_{i} \longrightarrow \sum_{i \in I}N_{i}$ given by $(x_{i})_{i \in I} \mapsto \sum_{i \in I}x_{i}$ is an isomorphism.
The reason I'm asking is because my lecture defined a sum of modules $\sum_{i \in I}N_{i}$ to be a direct sum written as $\bigoplus_{i \in I}N_{i}$ whenever the map $f$ is an isomorphism. This makes sense because in that case $\sum_{i \in I}N_{i} \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I}N_{i}$ so the notation is justified. But what if the internal and external sums are isomrphic in some other way? Then by this definition we cannot say that $\sum_{i \in I}N_{i}$ is a direct sum and cannot write it as $\bigoplus_{i \in I}N_{i}$.

Your map goes from the external to the internal sum so you should probably correct the title.

No, it need not be an isomorphism.
Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$ module $M = \oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}$, and the submodules $N_1 = M$ and $N_2=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\{0\}\oplus\{0\}\oplus\cdots$. Then $M=N_1+N_2$, $M\cong N_1\oplus N_2$, but the map $N_1\oplus N_2$ to $M$ given by $(n_1,n_2)\mapsto n_1+n_2$ is not an isomorphism, as it is not one-to-one: since $N_2\subseteq N_1$, take a nonzero $x\in N_2$ and take the element $(-x,x)$, which maps to $0$.

Very cool answer
